# End Key is not working

Tags: 12.04, keyboard, hardware

I have ubuntu 12.04. My end key on keyboard is not working. I have tried `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` but to no avail. It is frustrating because I am habitual with the end key in my typing. Please help! Thank You.

Comment: Which applications have you tried using it in?  Are you able to test if it is working on other operating systems (does it work when using the Ubuntu Live CD)?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `xev` to find out if pressing the key yields some result.  If yes, then it's probably a configuration issue.  If nothing happens when pressing the `End` key, then it's probably a hardware issue.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a hardware problem possibly.. try the keyboard on another computer to find out.

Also, as a stop-gap you can use ctrl+a and ctrl+e as home/end (the emacs way) which I much prefer personally.